# Negative power of 2

Tags: c, types

I am learning the characteristics of the different data type. For example, this program increasingly prints the power of 2 with four different formats: `integer, unsigned integer, hexadecimal, octal`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int i, val = 1;
        for (i = 1; i < 35; ++i) {
                printf("%15d%15u%15x%15o\n", val, val, val, val);
        val *= 2;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

It works. `unsigned` goes up to `2147483648`. `integer` goes up to `-2147483648`. But why does it become negative?

I have a theory: is it because the maximum signed integer we can represent on a 32 bit machine is `2147483647`? If so, why does it return the negative number?

Comment: your theory is right. overlow happens

Comment: Your program causes a *signed integer overflow* which is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: as often, because *undefined behavior* is undefined. signed integer overflow *is* undefined. A somewhat likely outcome is a wrap-around into the negative area, but that's not guaranteed -> your program doesn't have defined behavior.

Comment: Thank you guys for confirming my suspect. Do you suggest any reference to help me better comprehend undefined behaviors such as that?

Comment: [Consult the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Contents) for better understanding of all aspects of C. [Here is a section](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) that summarizes undefined behaviors.

Comment: "I have a theory: is it because the maximum signed integer we can represent on a 32 bit machine is 2147483647" - That's not even guaranteed for `int` and definitively not for all integer types.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBowling for the reference!

Comment: Thanks @Olaf for your note.

Comment: Code has 2 sources of UB, the potential `int` overflow of `val *= 2;` (identified by many) and printing an `int val` using `%15u%15x%15o` when `val < 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should understand that this program is *undefined*. It causes *signed integer overflow*, and this is declared *undefined* in the C Standard.

The technical reason is that no behavior can be predicted as different representations are allowed for negative numbers and there could even be *padding bits* in the representation.

The most probable reason you see a negative number in your case is that your machine uses *2's complement* (look it up) to represent negative numbers while arithmetics operate on bits without overflow checks. Therefore, the highest bit is the sign bit, and if your value overflows into this bit, it turns negative.

Comment: Thanks a lot Felix for your concise explanation!

Comment: The " reason you see a negative number" misleads.  1) had a rare non-2's complement machine been used, a  negative number may have appeared too.  2) The  2's complement idea does provide a potential explanation why the particular value  `-2147483648` was seen and not some other value,  3) It's all UB anyways, even if the machine is 2's complement.

Comment: @chux the fact that it's *undefined* is explained in the very first paragraph and I think that last one is worded so it's clear that 2's complement is *one* possible (and very likely) reason for the actual wraparound? What would you change in the wording to make that clearer?

Comment: The last says "reason you see a negative number is that your machine probably uses 2's complement ..." is the weakest part.  The reason for some negative number is not 2's complement.

Comment: Another, more important reason is some architectures use saturation arithmetics for signed integers, i.e. a result is capped at the max/min value, hence never will under-/overflow. This is typical for e.g. DSPs where the toolchain explicitly defines this behaviour or the program code can enforce it for a part of the code by setting a machine flag.

Comment: @chux @ Olaf I didn't intend to make an exhaustive list of possible reasons to observe what OP observed ... but I'll change the wording to emphasize this is just *one* guess I consider very probable in OP's case.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is UB caused by integer overflow. Since the behavior is undefined, anything could happen (*“When the compiler encounters [a given undefined construct] it is legal for it to make demons fly out of your nose”*), BUT, what actually happens on *some* machines (I suspect yours included) is this:

You start with `int val = 1;`. That is represented `0b00...1` in binary form. Each time you `val *= 2;` the value is multiplied by 2, therefore the representation changes to `0b00...10` and then to `0b00...100` and so on (the `1` bit moves one step each time). The last time you `val *= 2;` you get `0b100...`. Now, using 2's complement (which is what I guess your machine uses, as it very common) the value is actually `-1 * 0b1000...` which is `-2147483648`

Note, that even though this might be what's really going on in your machine, it's not to be trusted or thought of as the "right" thing to happen, since, as mentioned before, this is UB

Comment: NMDV yet `int` overflow is undefined behavior -UB.  This answer seems to explain why something happened as if that is the specified and expected behavior - which it is not.  It is just a common outcome of UB that may differ tomorrow.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input :) Yet, this is a common output and UB doesn't mean we can't predict the outcome (on specific machine), it just means the standard did not specify it...

Comment: True that UB can be predicted and like the weather, it might be wrong.  The key being, even if the outcome matches our prediction today, the outcome is not reliably for the future - thus UB.  For learners, instilling a sense of consistency concerning UB leads to weak programs that rely on that.

Comment: Close. The last line should read: "the value is actually `-1 * 0b100000...` which is `-2147483648`" since negation in 2's complement is calculated as `-a == ~a + 1`.

Comment: @chux I agree with you that any UB should be clearly stated as such on this site, as none of our readers should ever rely on any behavior that's actually UB. Nevertheless, UB is where the abstractions leak, and explaining why a specific UB construct produces a specific behavior can be quite insightful for those who have not ventured looking behind the abstractions yet. Thus, I find answers like this one quite helpful.

Comment: @cmaster Agree, yet the original answer was not explaining UB - it was attempting to explain behavior.  It did not identifying it as UB.  With the UB labelling and caution added, it is improved.

Comment: @chux Ah, I see.

Answer (score -1):

In this program, the `val` value will overflow, if it is a 32- bit machine, because the size of integer is 4 bytes. Now, we have 2 type of values in math, positive and negative, so to do calculation involving negative results, we use sign representations i.e `int` or `char` in C language.

Lets take the example of `char`, range -128 to 127, `unsigned char` range 0-255 .
It tells, range is divided into two parts for signed representation. So for any signed variable, if it crosses its range of +ve value, it goes into negative value. Like here in case of `char`, as the value goes above the 127, it becomes -ve. And suppose if you add 300 to any `char` or `unsigned char` variable what happens, it rolls over and starts again from zero.

```
char a=2;
a+=300;
```

what is the value?? now you know max value of `char` is 255(total 256 values, including zero), so 300-256 = 44 + 2 =46.
 Hope this helps

Comment: "In this program, the val value will overflow" - no. "if it is a 32- bit machine, because the size of integer is 4 bytes" - integers can have any size, depending on type. And the width of the machine is not directly related to the width of the integer types. 68K for instance is considered a 32 bit architecture, but uses 16 and 32 bit `int`, depending on ABI. " char, range -128 to 127" - not guaranteed and not true for most machines. etc. Your answer is full of wrong assumptions. And `char c = 127; c + 1;` does not overflow, even for `CHAR_MAX == 127` (which implies signed `char`).

Comment: can you please give any reference, so that i can clarify this.

Comment: There is only one autoritative reference for C. ISO9899:2011.